# raw data insert using cmd in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, syntax-error

I want to insert data into a table 'adminuser' using command line in laravel 5.

```
DB::table(`adminuser`)->insert([`id`:`1`,`username`:`admin`,`password`:`password`,`userlevel`:`1`])
```

But got this error

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

May be the syntax is error. But can't find the correct syntax.

Anybody help please

Comment: Did you read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database)?

Comment: Do you write a command for laravel? or just run your code in terminal?

Comment: Jeroen Heier... I can't find the specific docs. May be the searching keyword was not appropriate. Will you please share the link ?

Comment: ramin ashrafimanesh...run my code in terminal

Comment: you should run the code in Laravel Tinker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use php artisan tinker:

```
in terminal write this command and press enter > php artisan tinker

DB::table('adminuser')->insert(['id'=>'1','username'=>'admin','password'=>'password','userlevel'=>'1']);
```

Comment: ...absolutely right !! I just forgot the 'tinker'... thanks a lot ..... :)